# Error while using yarn add pg-hstore: patch-package not found

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I'm trying to use `sequelize` in my react-app, and already added `sequelize`, `sequelize-cli` and `pg` through `yarn add`, but when trying to add `pg-hstore` this error appears:

```
yarn add v1.22.18
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
error /Users/currentuser/Desktop/project/node_modules/underscore: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: patch-package
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/currentuser/Desktop/project/node_modules/underscore
Output:
/bin/sh: patch-package: command not found
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I have no idea how to solve this, any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Same error when installing firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the post install script in package.json: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/68e5eb68635548846b4663479b9d0fc78d090b0a/package.json#L95

It has been fixed in version 1.13.6, released several hours ago:
https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/releases/tag/1.13.6

Just run `yarn add` again and it should be fine.

Hope this helps!